# mksdcard to create a virtual sdcard for avd?

Tags: android, sdk

Please suggest the code to make a sdcard in AVD (virtual device) ?

The command

"mksdcrad -1 sdcard 256M Mysdcard " is not creating a virtual sdcard  ?

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/mksdcard.html. might help. Are you using eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

The command is : `mksdcard 64M D:\FileName.img`

- `64M` is 64 MB of size
- `D:\` is directory in you want to keep SD card
- `FileName.img` is name of file

Answer (score 0):

IMHP you've erroneusly put -1 (digit) with the correct -l (letter) .
Have fun!